# Looking for an elegant way to replace multiple if clauses connotated by OR

Tags: php

Currently I have this

```
if (strpos($body, 'aff_id=') !== false ||
strpos($body, 'MJ12bot') !== false ||
strpos($body, 'Yahoo! Slurp') !== false || ...)
{

}
```

I want to create a `textwerbung.txt`, in which I put

```
aff_id=
MJ12bot
Yahoo! Slurp
...
```

Then I want php to convert this into the previous.

My approach

```
$zeilen = file ('textwerbung.txt');
$gefunden = false;
for ($i = 0;$i<count($zeilen);$i++)
{
  if (strpos($body, $zeilen[$i]) !== false
  {
    $gefunden = true;
  }  
}
if ($gefunden)
{

}
```

What is more elegant?

Comment: You can even put a `break;` after `$gefunden = true;`; you don't need to do more checks after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

This might improve it a bit:

```
$zeilen = file('textwerbung.txt');

$gefunden = false;
foreach ($zeilen as $z) {
    if (strpos($body, $z) !== false) {
        $gefunden = true;
    }  
}

if ($gefunden) {

}
```